# knitr source code box width

Tags: r, knitr

knitr offers helpful background shading for blocks of code.  The resulting shaded panels are slightly wider than the rest of the text in an article.  How can I get code panels with shading the same width as text sections?  (You can see the extra width in the panels of code in Yihui's book.)

Comment: Can you point out the page number of the code block that you were talking about? I did not notice the extra width (Germans are probably better at observing the differences :). Anyway, here is how knitr defined the LaTeX environment `kframe` for code blocks: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/misc/knitr.sty

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  It is true of pretty well every block in my copy of your book.  It is more noticeable if you draw a figure on a grey shaded background with the code above it on a similarly shaded background, which is what I would like to do (e.g., with grey93).  I'll check it.